# Valgrind fails to create log files - "Permission denied"

Tags: linux, valgrind, memcheck

I am running a Linux application consisting of several executables. They are structured like this:

**base_app** is run under superuser and creates **su_app** and **non_su_app** via fork

**non_su_app** needs to be run with normal user privileges, not superuser. For that I call `setegid` and `setepid` after the fork call

Now I want to do some memory profiling on these apps with valgrind and collect the profiling logs separately for each process. I run

```
sudo valgrind --tool=memcheck --trace-children=yes --leak-check=full --show-leak-kinds=all --log-file=/tmp/log_files/valgrind-%p /path/to/base_app
```

which works fine for **base_app** and **su_app** but when the code tries to launch **non_su_app** I get

```
valgrind: Cannot create log file '/tmp/log_files/valgrind-15056': Permission denied
```

over and over. And the app fails to start completely.

I tried  changing the permissions of the log folder to 777 or doing something like

```
valgrind --tool=memcheck --trace-children=yes --leak-check=full --show-leak-kinds=all --log-file=/tmp/log_files/valgrind-%p sudo /path/to/base_app
```

to no avail. Are there any ways to properly collect to logs from these processes?

Comment: I think the problem is that `valgrind` tries to re-open the log file after it execs `non_su_app`. The file is only writable to root, so this fails.

Comment: Is there any way to work around the issue?

Comment: What happens if you use a directory other than tmp?

Comment: (/tmp has the restricted deletion flag)